# References to tenets of Samanya dharma in Sruti

Tags: dharma

The various tenets of Samanya dharma like Satya, Ahimsa, Shaucha, Asteya and Indriya Nigraha etc. are present in various Smritis, Puranas, and even Mahabharata.

Can anybody give references to them individually or collectively in Sruti- Veda Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka or in Upanishads?

Thank you,
Nithin

Comment: Can anybody reply?

Comment: Are you referring to the Niyamas?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyama The Niyamas are described in Patanjali's Yoga Sutras, and thus they may also be described in some of the Yoga Upanishdads. Now personally I think the Yoga Upanishads are interpolations, but we've had that argument before :-) In any case, outside the Yoga Upanishads, I highly doubt that a rule against stealing would be mentioned anywhere in the Samhitas, Brahmanas, or Aranyakas. That's more the province of Dharma Shastras like the Manu Smriti. It's possible an Upanishad other than the Yoga ones may mention stealing though.

Comment: We have states like Satyam Vada, Dharmam Chara in Taittiriya Upanishad. I was looking for more such statements in Shruti- Samhita, Braahmana, Aranyaka, and Upanishads.